# Why can't I delete this perforce changelist?

Tags: perforce, changelist

I'm new to perforce and somehow I've gotten myself into a weird state.

I have two files that I modified and somehow added to a change list (not the default changelist). I want to revert the changes and delete the changelist but I can't figure it out.

I have tried doing this:

```
p4 change -d 75697
Change 75697 has 2 open file(s) associated with it and can't be deleted.
```

So I tried to revert the files in the change list:

```
p4 revert package.json
package.json - file(s) not opened on this client.
```

Okay, so I guess I need to open the file?

```
p4 edit package.json
//a/b/c/package.json - can't edit (already opened on this client)
```

So I can't revert the file until I open it but I can't open it because it's already open? What's the deal?

Answer (score 3):

You could be getting that error because your local `package.json` doesn't map to the actual depot path that's open (due to something tricky you've done with your client view since opening the file).  It's hard to say without seeing more command output, but try just:

```
p4 revert -c 75697 //...
```

to revert all files in that changelist regardless of their paths.

If that doesn't work, check with your Perforce admin; either they've put you into some really weird permissions bind (i.e. they've revoked the access level to the files that you need in order to revert them) that they should undo, or they'll need to do a bit of light db maintenance (`p4d -xf 925`) to fix an inconsistency.